# passing jQuery object references not working when called by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, reference, load, flot

I have spent a day working on a script that should have been relatively simple to implement. It however was not.

Essentially what I wanted to do was as follows.
Have 5 buttons which onclick load a flot (jQuery plugin) graph into a div.

So, I have my file, flot.php which takes a parameter 'type' in the url. This parameter tells flot which graph to load.

Flot requires jQuery and the relevant flot files to work. Now my index.php file includes these files BUT because flot.php is called by Ajax, it is essentially stand alone.. because flot.php doesn't include the same headers i have to include the relevant js files in flot.php for it to work.. Right?

Now in flot.php i use `jQuery.getScript` to get my json. This is within a `document.ready()` statement, so for this to be called the relevant graph containers etc must be loaded.. right?

On returning the data, I pass the data to another function which does the actual plotting.

I call `plotMultiLines($('#<?php echo $id ?>'), o.data);`

This passes a reference to my container object, and my data.

Initially i did the following:

```
$.plot($plot.find(".placeholder"),data,options);
```

where `$plot` references the jQuery object I passed in.

When I access flot.php?type=graph1 directly, this setup works perfectly. The data is loaded and the graph is plotted.

However when I load it through Ajax in index.php it does not.

Although `console.log($plot.find(".placeholder"));` displays the object passed in, it seemingly does not work for plotting the graph.

If i change this to simply `$(".placeholder")` it works again.

The same is the case for hover actions with flot. When i bind the action it works fine when accessed directly but only works with `$(".placeholder")` when accessed via ajax.

Now the reason I pass the jQuery object is because i was told too :) Apparently it is good for some reason. If someone could enlighten me on that too it would be appreciated.

So yes.. why is this occurring? Why do the passed objects not seem to work with flot when called from an ajax request?

Many many thanks.

Comment: Either I have misunderstood or "... have to include the relevant js files in flot.php  ..." doesn't sound right. I would guess that  flot.php is a script that returns XML or JSON, from which javascript already in place on the page (in the client) will compose and render your graph.

Comment: No. flot.php contains my graph containers and the respective functions which call an external file to get the response.

Comment: You also mention index.php.

Comment: Yes..? Index.php is the file which loads flot.php through an ajax request. Flot then calls a third file which returns some json.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. I would need to see actual code.